# Disabling Microphone playback

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I'm having a strange problem with my headset, whenever I plug in my headset I get microphone playback. When I go to Recording Devices -> Properties -> Listen -> Listen to this device, it's turned off. If I enable it, I can hear myself twice through the speakers. Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't have this problem with my laptop or other desktop.

Comment: What kind of head-set is it exactly?  How does it attach to the system?  Have you tried another Microphone or headset to see if it behaves the same way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to turn off microphone playback through the speaker’s Control Panel settings:

1. Right-click the speaker icon in the notification area
2. Select *Playback devices*
3. Right-click the output device
4. Select *Properties*
5. Click the *Levels* tab
6. Find the *Microphone* device
7. Click the speaker icon next to the microphone to mute it
8. Click `[OK]` in the two dialog boxes

[image: Screenshots of steps to mute microphone output in Windows 7]

Comment: +1 but are you sure this is not "Recording devices"?

Comment: Yes, that is a [different set of tabs and dialogs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4XIyv.png). (I for one prefer to set every aspect of the microphone to the lowest settings and muted… and cover the camera.)

Comment: http://imgur.com/ZhceV3I I don't have an option under levels for Microphone sadly :/

Comment: In windows 8 there is another option at the microphone Properties (Recording Devices => Properties) "Listent to this device"

Comment: How do you get this to show up in the mixer for convenience?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10:

1. open *Sound settings*
2. click on *App volume and device preferences*
   [image: App volume and device preferences]
3. set the Output to *Realtek Digital Output* (or whatever output device you're using).
   [image: Select your output device]

Comment: This is identical to the accepted answer just not as good.

Comment: This solution worked for me (on Windows 10), while the accepted answer was not an option (the settings did not include "microphone" in the "levels" tab).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several things to try right off the bat:

- This could be a result of the headset using special software to manage the headset without using the default Windows software.
- This device might not be made for PC (The conclusion of this thread: http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Headphones-Headsets-Microphones/F540-Continuous-playback-Open-Mic-Listen-to-device-in-recording/td-p/609062)
- The drivers might need to be updated.

Comment: In my case I needed to Realtek HD Audio Manager and mute the playback level.

Answer (score 0):

I have one modification to step 3 of [Anonymouse's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1401007/911683):

3. In *App volume and device preferences*, set this level to zero:

[image]

This volume is giving you self-feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Samson C01U Pro` mic as both mic and sound card, with `Samson Sound Deck` software, there is a special button to disable microphone output to headphones
[image: Samson Sound Deck]

Answer (score 0):

After having gone through all the above solutions, with no success, even when the Mic was supposedly disabled, I felt as if there was another MIC set up.
Sure enough - the solution was to be found in the Realtek Audio Manager:

[image]