# Quickly toggle microphone playback (sidetone)

Tags: windows-10, audio, shortcuts, microphone, playback

first post here.

I would like to quickly be able to toggle microphone playback through speakers (side tone). The specific steps and settings I am referring too can be seen here:
https://superuser.com/a/713809

or in this photo:
[https://i.gyazo.com/f4ef6e640c2c1ea008c8dbd463693398.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKyqn.png)

I really enjoy creating batch or other quick short cuts that cut down on the steps to perform tasks. In this example, I use a third party amp with optional headphone out, sometimes the headphones are present, but sometimes they are not and the side tone can be very loud.

Is there anyway to create a shortcut or registry modifier to change this setting on the fly?

Comment: After using a Sysinternals, I located something that might be of interest:
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices`

I noticed has a key change when I toggle:
`"{1e94c58f-3e40-4ddb-b10c-a86d8b870a31},2"=hex:02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00`
`"{1e94c58f-3e40-4ddb-b10c-a86d8b870a31},2"=hex:02,00,8f,d5,01,00,00,00,00,00`

But, running the exported .reg results in a failure for "some keys are open by the system or other processes, or you have insufficient privileges"

Answer (score 0):

I really was not expecting to figure out how to do this, but I have found a third party utility SoundVolumeView by NirSoft that can monitor and change audio properties, it also has the ability to create shortcuts for these items.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html